# Laravel 9 sub-query target linked model columns in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working inside a Laravel 9 project and am trying to perform a query and return my `Monitor` model where the `User` role of the monitor is a customer (eventually adding more fields).

My current query attempt throws an error:

> Property [user] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

What am I missing?

```php
/**
 * Get inactive users
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getInactiveUsersWithMonitors()
{
    $monitors = Monitor::with('user')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->user->where('role', 'customer');
    })->get();

    return $monitors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already defined the `user` function in the `Monitor` model. Here is what you should do.

```
/**
 * Get inactive users
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getInactiveUsersWithMonitors()
{
    /* $monitors = Monitor::with('user')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->user->where('role', 'customer');
    })->get(); */

     $monitors = Monitor::whereHas('user', function($query)
{
    $query->where('role', 'customer');

})->get();
    

    return $monitors;
}
```

This will get all the details from the `monitors` table as well as the corresponding details from `users` table.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but this isn't what I asked. I need to only return Monitors where the linked model User role is a customer, later adding more conditions.

Comment: Okay. Now I get your point. I am updating the code

Comment: What kind of relationship did you define?

Comment: A `User` can have many monitors.

Comment: I have updated the code. That should work. Give me a feedback.